# How can I prevent file copying from a pen drive? (No external softwares)

Tags: copy, usb, mp3, storage

I want to place files (MP3s) in a pen drive and only allow users access to listen to the files in the drive but not be able to **copy or edit** these files.

And yes I know there are usb copy protect softwares but what they usually do is embed the files into an exe file along with required restrictions, but I want the mp3 files to be playable not just in computers but also in cars, TV's and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No way. If the data can be extracted (in order to be played), it can be saved elsewhere, i.e. copied.

In the worst case one can put a recorder near the sound system and record your music (and this is how many rips are made, especially in cinemas).